React Hook Form's useFieldArray's remove method is not deleting the item ( State does not get updated)
I am unable to remove the deleted item from arrayFields, even though I am calling the removeArrayField (remove) method with correct arguments. My state does not change even after calling the remove method
executive-form.tsx
import { getRadioButtonYesNoOptions } from '@company-onboarding/company-onboarding.data';
import { getUpdatedPercentageFieldsBasedOnEntityType } from '@company-onboarding/company-onboarding.utils';
import { useUpsertExecutives } from '@company-onboarding/hooks/useUpsertExecutives';
import { getSumOfAllExecutiveEquities } from '@components/onboarding/onboarding-form.helpers';
import { PayloadType } from '@components/onboarding/onboarding-form.utils';
import {
  BlockSeparator,
  PrimaryButton,
  PrimaryOptionsInput,
  ShadowCover,
} from '@paf-ui-components-library';
import { useEntriesToData, useToast } from '@paf-ui-components-library/hooks';
import {
  BusinessEntitiesType,
  BusinessExecutiveType,
  CompanyDueDiligenceDto,
  DirectorInformationInputDto,
  IndividualBeneficialOwnerInputDto,
  LegalEntityBeneficialOwnerInputDto,
  ManagementInformationInputDto,
  OwnerRelationshipToBusiness,
} from '@utils/interfaces-graphql';
import { useStoreActions } from '@utils/store';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useFieldArray, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import { ExecutiveDetails } from './ExecutiveDetails';

export type SubmitExecutiveDataType = {
  individualBeneficialOwners?: IndividualBeneficialOwnerInputDto[];
  legalEntityBeneficialOwners?: LegalEntityBeneficialOwnerInputDto[];
  managementExecutives?: ManagementInformationInputDto[];
  boardDirectors?: DirectorInformationInputDto[];
  indexToUpdate?: number;
};

interface IProps {
  executiveType: BusinessExecutiveType;
  prefix: string;
  onUpdateExecutive: (data: SubmitExecutiveDataType) => void;
  shouldPrefill: boolean;
}

export const BusinessExecutiveForm: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  executiveType,
  onUpdateExecutive,
  prefix,
  shouldPrefill,
}) => {
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const radioButtonOptions = getRadioButtonYesNoOptions();

  const { updateCustomerData } = useStoreActions((actions) => actions);
  const { OWNER_RELATIONSHIP_TO_BUSINESS } = useEntriesToData({
    OwnerRelationshipToBusiness,
  });

  const { control, getValues, resetField, setValue, watch } = useFormContext();
  const { handleDeleteExecutivesById } = useUpsertExecutives(executiveType);

  const businessEntityType = watch('companyProfile.entityType') as BusinessEntitiesType;

  const {
    append: appendArrayField,
    fields: arrayFields,
    remove: removeArrayField,
  } = useFieldArray({ control, name: prefix });

  const isBeneficialOwner = [
    BusinessExecutiveType.IndividualBeneficialOwner,
    BusinessExecutiveType.LegalEntityBeneficialOwner,
  ].includes(executiveType);

  const handleAddExecutive = () => {
    if (isBeneficialOwner) {
      const { totalEquity } = getSumOfAllExecutiveEquities(getValues() as CompanyDueDiligenceDto);
      if (totalEquity >= 100) {
        toast({
          message: t('errors.existing_owners_already_owns_100_percent_equity'),
          type: 'error',
        });
        return;
      }
    }
    appendArrayField({});
  };

  const handleRemoveExecutive = async (index: number) => {
    let shouldRemove = true;
    const executiveId = watch(prefix)?.[index]?._id;

    if (executiveId) {
      const finalResponse = await handleDeleteExecutivesById({
        executiveId,
        executiveType,
      });
      if (finalResponse) {
        updateCustomerData({
          type: PayloadType.COMPANY_DUE_DILIGENCE,
          data: finalResponse,
        });

        console.log({
          finalResponse,
        });
      } else {
        // set should remove false if failed to delete
        shouldRemove = false;
      }
    }

    // If its last executive and is not beneficial owner then reset fields instead of removing it
    if (shouldRemove && (arrayFields.length > 1 || isBeneficialOwner)) {
      console.log({
        index,
        arrayFields,
      });
      // setTimeout(() => {
      //   removeArrayField(index);
      // }, 100);

      removeArrayField(index);
    } else {
      resetField(prefix, { defaultValue: [{}] });
    }

    // Debugging State
    console.log('After removal or reset:', {
      arrayFields,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldPrefill) {
      // TODO: To handle the case when filling different percentage field
      // const individualBeneficialOwners = watch('selectedMeritId.individualBeneficialOwners') || [];
      // const individualOwner = individualBeneficialOwners[0] || {};

      const executivePrefillingData = getUpdatedPercentageFieldsBasedOnEntityType(
        watch(`selectedMeritId.${prefix}`) || [{}],
        businessEntityType,
      );

      if (executiveType === BusinessExecutiveType.IndividualBeneficialOwner) {
        setValue('isLegalOrIndividualOwnersExist', 'YES');
      }
      setValue(prefix, executivePrefillingData);
    }
  }, []);

  console.log({
    length: arrayFields.length,
    arrayFields,
  });
  return (
    <>
      {arrayFields.map((field, index) => (
        <ExecutiveDetails
          executiveType={executiveType}
          headerTitle={t(`${executiveType.toLowerCase()}.array_field_title`, {
            count: index + 1 + field.id,
          })}
          isHideDeleteButton={index === 0 && !isBeneficialOwner && !watch(prefix)?.[0]?._id}
          key={field.id}
          onRemove={() => handleRemoveExecutive(index)}
          onUpdate={() => {
            onUpdateExecutive({
              [prefix]: watch(prefix) || [],
              indexToUpdate: index,
            });
          }}
          prefix={`${prefix}.${index}`}
        >
          {/* Business relationship is only for Individual Beneficial Owners */}
          {executiveType === BusinessExecutiveType.IndividualBeneficialOwner && (
            <ShadowCover
              description={t(`${executiveType.toLowerCase()}.relation_to_business_description`)}
              title={t(`${executiveType.toLowerCase()}.relation_to_business`)}
            >
              <PrimaryOptionsInput
                data={OWNER_RELATIONSHIP_TO_BUSINESS.filter(
                  ({ value }) => value !== OwnerRelationshipToBusiness.None,
                )}
                name={`${prefix}.${index}.relationToBusiness`}
                type="checkbox"
              />
            </ShadowCover>
          )}

          {/* Only for Board directors */}
          {executiveType === BusinessExecutiveType.BoardDirector && (
            <PrimaryOptionsInput
              className="grid-1x2"
              data={radioButtonOptions}
              heading={t(`${executiveType.toLowerCase()}.is_director_also_manager`)}
              name={`${prefix}.${index}.isDirectorManager`}
              type="radio"
            />
          )}
        </ExecutiveDetails>
      ))}

      <BlockSeparator>
        <ShadowCover>
          <PrimaryButton
            className="add-array-field-button"
            onClick={handleAddExecutive}
            type="button"
            variantsStyle={['primary-button-accent', 'primary-button-transparent']}
          >
            {t(`${executiveType.toLowerCase()}.add_executive_button_text`)}
          </PrimaryButton>
        </ShadowCover>
      </BlockSeparator>
    </>
  );
};


The issue lies in handleRemoveExecutive method :-
  const handleRemoveExecutive = async (index: number) => {
    let shouldRemove = true;
    const executiveId = watch(prefix)?.[index]?._id;

    if (executiveId) {
      const finalResponse = await handleDeleteExecutivesById({
        executiveId,
        executiveType,
      });
      if (finalResponse) {
        updateCustomerData({
          type: PayloadType.COMPANY_DUE_DILIGENCE,
          data: finalResponse,
        });

        console.log({
          finalResponse,
        });
      } else {
        // set should remove false if failed to delete
        shouldRemove = false;
      }
    }

    // If its last executive and is not beneficial owner then reset fields instead of removing it
    if (shouldRemove && (arrayFields.length > 1 || isBeneficialOwner)) {
      console.log({
        index,
        arrayFields,
      });
      // this successfully the deleted item from the arrayFields
      // setTimeout(() => {
      //   removeArrayField(index);
      // }, 100);

      removeArrayField(index);
    } else {
      resetField(prefix, { defaultValue: [{}] });
    }

    // Debugging State
    console.log('After removal or reset:', {
      arrayFields,
    });
  };

removeArrayField(index) does not removes the deleted item from arrayFields but if I were to use this method in a setTimeOut, the deleted item also gets removed successfully from arrayFields

Your code looks good and should work as expected. If it's not, please create a minimal blank app that only reproduce the issue without any other functionality
